# What's another word for "fancy knowledge"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to describe how politicians are using "fancy knowledge" to trick citizens. What word or words will suit to deliver the idea?

Comment: You put _"fancy knowledge"_ in scare quotes. I've never heard the phrase before. Where did you hear it? Did you invent it? What does it mean? Is it different from _lies_?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please can you give a specific example of this. Perhaps from a newspaper with a link to the text. That way we can see what you are referring to.

Comment: One possible word is "disinformation" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disinformation

Comment: My  grand-parents used to call it "book larnin'"...what register are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

When a government (corporation, etc) puts forward interpretations of scientifically collated data in such a way that the average person doesn't understand exactly how the ensuing decisions were made ('Polcaster is in Covid-avoidance Level four for the next three months'), though it speaks as though the rulings were indisputable based on the evidence, it is often said to be **baffling [the population] with science**. A fixed expression, too transparent to be called an idiom.

> - ... *learned that these emissions included a chemical substance known as dioxin, experts baffled them with science and told them that
>   dioxin was not a problem.*

[Robert Allen_The Dioxin War... Truth and Lies](https://pdfslide.net/documents/robert-allen-the-dioxin-war-truth-and-lies-aboubookfiorg.html)

One might say 'The science is wrong', but it's more accurate to say that the way scientific results are analysed, presented and acted upon is often incompetent or skewed to favour an already decided agenda. *Which may not per se be the wrong aganda*, we must remember.

Trying to trick people by the clever use of language (obviously related, but not necessarily involving the spinning of detailed knowledge) is *obscurantism*, *dissimulation* ...  *spin* in its usual negative register.

If the language is in a scientific/technical register (again, there is no requirement for skilfully presented data), the term *technobabble* is often used.

Comment: "Clever use of language" aka "weasel words".

Comment: So ELU is devoted to studying weasel words?

Comment: "Obscurantism" describes the whole current of thought that tends in many more ways than the use of unnecessarily complicated language to suppress or slow the dissemination of knowledge, enlightenment in general. The practice of trying to trick people by the clever use of language is at most  a peculiarity in that trend which most of all is a collective one.

Comment: But M-W, and doubtless other dictionaries, license the non-global usage: 'obscurantism 2b: an act or instance of obscurantism'. We must allow secondary (etc) usages as being correct. That's why dictionaries list them.

Answer (score 1):

*Baffle them with* *Bovine Excrement* is the accurate if less colorful phrasing of expression.

You may be looking for a single word for *specialized knowledge* that they pretend to have, just long enough to distract the child like listener so they can take credit for solving the problem. *Junk Science* is another two word possibility. I'll settle for *Crap*. More's the pity.